# where is this 'helper' imported from in Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am reviewing the Activator websockets template and there is the following view:

```
@(message: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@import helper._

@main("Websocket Stateless DEMO") {
```

where is this 'helper' import coming from?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `Rendering an <input> element` section in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers), you'll find out that all helpers are placed at the `views.html.helper` package. Since the view you mentioned is located in the `views.html` package the import can be relatively shorter.